# Animated movie where there some people who fly with robotics suits

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation, cyborg

I don’t honestly remember much; it’s an animated movie I watched eight or so years ago.

The suits might have been a part of their body or not, I don’t remember. They allowed them to fly and were some kind of weapon, and then some of those people go on a mission and realize there are some cyborgs which they didn’t think existed or something like that?

It’s an animated movie, but its style and appearance of everything are similar to video games or animated movies like *Resident Evil: Vendetta* and *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children*? There is also the possibility I’m mixing the events of two animated series with each other, but I’m sure about the flying suits part.

There a scenes I remember that a character flies one of those suits in daytime beside a skyscraper and smashes thorough one of the windows and kills someone white or gray haired? And he was retired or no longer in his best shape to wear them or something?

Basically,

It was a single whole length animated movie not related to anything else.
The style was similar to video games or animations like Resident Evil: Vendetta_ and *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children*

Watched it in a cousin’s house, about 8 or 10 years ago. It was probably a dvd but he could’ve pirated and downloaded it too, I don’t exactly remember.
The year of production would be around 2008-2012 or maybe higher? I’m sure it had high graphics but maybe the feeling of nostalgia is affecting me.

A character I remember clearly or maybe not was a guy with white or gray hair who wore a purple vest. Maybe he was young or middle aged. At first he seemed or was like an ally but became an antagonist later. One of the characters wore a purple robot suit, flew beside a skyscraper, fought someone or something and then smashed through one of the windows and caught the gray haired guy. There was also maybe a helicopter at the beginning. Main character looked like Sam from metal gear solid rising and vengeance overall. Mostly his hair. There were a lot of skyscrapers and a large grassy area with a pound in front of them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  What kind of a mission was it?  (Hostage rescue, search and retrieval, infiltration...)

Comment: Thank you for responding, in a cousin’s house? Sorry, that’s not probably gonna help much...  I don’t remember anything about what kind of mission it was. Now that I think about it the main character was a cyborg too?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: try (the many) ghost in the shell or appleseed